# Postman doesn't have the required permissions to install Node.js and other dependencies

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postman

When I try to install interceptor to use cookies in postman I get the error that is mentioned in header. OS is linux.

I googled the error description but it is not mentioned anywhere. Any idea would be really helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is not any answer here yet. But I found a workaround that is installing PostmanCanary. I couldn't install interceptor to Postman in Linux but I installed it to PostmanCanary successfully and it works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, though I got the error code `CHROME_NOT_INSTALLED` as well. The solution was too simple: I had Chromium installed, not Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

As per the troubleshooting tips it could happen if `NativeMessagingHosts` directory is missing,

this can be solved by creating `NativeMessagingHosts` directory in `~/.config/google-chrome/` in case of `linux`.

Reference: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/interceptor/#troubleshooting-tips

Answer (score 1):

And if desired to use interceptor on any other chrome based browser like brave, do the following

1. find the `utils.js` file. in my system the path looked like
   `/opt/postman/app/resources/app/utils/interceptor/utils.js`
2. change the path of the key named `LINUX` to the path containing `NativeMessagingHosts` directory.

```js
const nativeMessagingHosts = {
    MACOS: '/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts/',
    LINUX: '/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/NativeMessagingHosts/',
    WINDOWS: 'HKCU\\Software\\Google\\Chrome\\NativeMessagingHosts\\'
  }
```

Here I changed the path from `/.config/google-chrome/NativeMessagingHosts` to `/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/NativeMessagingHosts/`

Now try to install the interceptor again.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have the following in the environment variable PATH:
`C:\Program Files\Nodejs\`

I have face same issue before, and later it got fixed.

Comment: The issue occurs on Linux, not windows.